# browser.downloads.download - images disappearing after download

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, browser-extension

So I was tinkering with a firefox extension and came across something I can't explain. This extension downloads images from a certain site when a browser action (button) is clicked. Can confirm that the rest of the extension works perfectly and the code below has proper access to the response object.

```
const downloading = browser.downloads.download({
    filename:response.fileName + '.jpg',
    url:response.src,
    headers:[{name:"Content-Type", value:"image/jpeg"}],
    saveAs:true,
    conflictAction:'uniquify'
});
        
const onStart = (id) => {console.log('started: '+id)};
const onError = (error) => {console.log(error)};
        
downloading.then(onStart, onError);
```

So the saveAs dialog pops up (filename with file extension populated), I click save, and then it downloads. As soon as the file finishes downloading it disappears from the folder it was saved in. I have no idea how this is happening.

Is this something wrong with my code, Firefox, or maybe a OS security action? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Extra Information: 
Firefox - 95.0.2 (64-bit)
macOS - 11.4 (20F71)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You have to put download in background, background.js.

Attached sample of Thunderbird addon creates new menu entry in the message list and save raw message to the file on click.

If you look to the manifest.json, "background.js" script is defined in the "background" section. The background.js script is automatically loaded when the add-on is enabled during Thunderbird start or after the add-on has been manually enabled or installed.

See:  [onClicked event from the browserAction (John Bieling)](https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/addons/Te54e273b11c1f2da-M74bdfeda1aa8f9c87e067f99/savas-toolbar-button-to-specific-location-and-name)

manifest.json:

```
{
  "description": "buttons",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "button",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "menus","messagesRead","downloads"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/page-16.png",
      "32": "icons/page-32.png"
    }
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
async function main() {
    // create a new context menu entry in the message list
    // the function defined in onclick will get passed a OnClickData obj
    // https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/menus.html#menus-onclickdata
    await messenger.menus.create({
        contexts: ["all"],
        id: "edit_email_subject_entry",
        onclick: (onClickData) => {
            saveMsg(onClickData.selectedMessages?.messages);
        },
        title: "iktatEml"
    });

    messenger.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
        let msgs = await messenger.messageDisplay.getDisplayedMessages(tab.id);
        saveMsg(msgs);
    })
}

async function saveMsg(MessageHeaders) {
    if (MessageHeaders && MessageHeaders.length > 0) {
        // get MessageHeader of first selected messages
        // https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messages.html#messageheader
        let MessageHeader = MessageHeaders[0];
        let raw = await messenger.messages.getRaw(MessageHeader.id);

        let blob = new Blob([raw], { type: "text;charset=utf-8" })

        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads
        await browser.downloads.download({
            'url': URL.createObjectURL(blob),
            'filename': "xiktatx.eml",
            'conflictAction': "overwrite",
            'saveAs': false
        });
    } else {
        console.log("No message selected");
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.